# How to make the Google search bar not use "table"

Tags: google-search-console

A site I'm working on uses [google's programmable search engine.](https://programmablesearchengine.google.com)

Google's html uses a <table> tag to encapsulate their search bar.

This creates the following error in [Wave accessibility evaluation tool](https://wave.webaim.org/)

**Alerts**

Layout table

**What It Means**

A layout table is present.

**Why It Matters**

Layout tables exist merely to position content visually - to create columns, insert spacing, or align content neatly for sighted users. Their content is not at all tabular in nature. Layout tables should not be used in HTML5. They can introduce reading and navigation order issues. Screen readers may interpret them as data tables (i.e., announcing column and row numbers), especially if they contain table header () cells. This introduces significant overhead on screen reader users.

**How to Fix It**

In almost every case, layout tables can be replaced with other HTML elements and styled with CSS to achieve the desired visual presentation. If the table contains tabular data, provide appropriate header () cells. If the layout table remains, verify that the reading and navigation order of table content (based on underlying source code order) is logical and give it role="presentation" to ensure it is not identified as a table to screen reader users.

**The Algorithm... in English**

A  element is present that does not contain any header () cells.

**Standards and Guidelines**

[1.3.1 Info and Relationships (Level A)](https://webaim.org/standards/wcag/checklist#sc1.3.1)

[1.3.2 Meaningful Sequence (Level A)](https://webaim.org/standards/wcag/checklist#sc1.3.2)

...

I made a jsfiddle demonstrating the issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/18zk2tuc/

```
<script async src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=517544a62690b41fb">
</script>
<div class="gcse-search"></div>
```

As the error says, semantically google's search bar is not a table. Is there a way to make google's programmable search engine not use <table> and allow me to use flex or something instead?

Comment: The `<table>` exists _within_ Google's own `<iframe>` content document - which also has a CSP that prevents host pages from fiddling with it - so I'd say you're SOL - and I wouldn't worry too much about that accessibility report, honestly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply ignore the error message from the Wave tool, because the tables used by Google have the `role="presentation"` attribute, which removes all semantics from the `table` element.

From [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/presentation_role#description):

> If `presentation` or `none` is applied to a `<table>` element, the descendant `<caption>`, `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, `<tfoot>`, `<tr>`, `<th>`, and `<td>` elements inherit the role and are thus not exposed to assistive technologies. But, elements inside of the `<th>` and `<td>` elements, including nested tables, are exposed to assistive technologies.

Comment: I have just contacted the WAVE maintainers via their [feedback form](https://wave.webaim.org/feedback) to make sure that I'm not wrong. Let's see what they say...

Comment: Just received this message from [Jared Smith](https://www.linkedin.com/in/jaredsmithsprofile/) from WebAIM which confirms my answer: _This is a WAVE Alert that is simply identifying that a layout table is present. It is not being identified as an "error", this it's not a false positive. The alert is simply prompting a manual check to ensure that it is not, in fact, a data table (which would necessitate additional markup for accessibility). Because this table is an actual layout table, the alert can simply be ignored, though adding role="presentation" is advised._

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the search box yourself:

```html
<form action="/search.html" id=search-form>
    <input type=hidden name=cx value="$googleCustomSearchId">
    <input type=hidden name=cof value="FORID:10">
    <input type=hidden name=ie value=UTF-8>
    <input type=text name=q size=16 placeholder=search>
    <input id=search-submit type=submit name=Search value=Search>
</form>
```

and then have it write the search results into `search.html`:

```html
<div id=cse-search-results></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var googleSearchIframeName = "cse-search-results";
    var googleSearchFormName = "cse-search-box";
    var googleSearchFrameWidth = 800;
    var googleSearchDomain = "www.google.com";
    var googleSearchPath = "/cse";
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/afsonline/show_afs_search.js"></script>
```

They used to document this, but I can't find it now. It still works fine though.